# responsive design will apply for both height nad width for site?

Tags: magento, responsive-design

we want to know about the responsive design for website. is it applies for

both height and width of the site . can we make a site responsive for height also?

please help me to find solution.

let me know if you have need clarification

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people tend to think of responsive design as being responsive to different screen **widths** which then allows users to view content optimally on any screen **but** does mean that they still must scroll to see more content below.

There is however also a school of thought around Vertically Responsive Design which looks at responsive design for height as well as width just as you're looking for.

There is a great article on this here:

http://www.nitinh.com/2013/03/vertically-responsive-design-keeping-things-above-the-fold/

It contains some good little CSS snippets to get you started, generally making use of viewport height to give optimal spacing and sizing for height as well as width using responsive design.

Most modern browser support viewport height but you could also use @media rules in much the same way as you would for width, setting different CSS rules for different screen heights with:

```
@media screen and  ( max-height:540px ){
somecss:rules;
}
```

There's some further reading on using @media for height here:

http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/height-based-media-queries.php

Hope this helps.